# How I can skip variable if undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i trying to get some data json from my api, But I faced this problem:

[image]

**Code javascript to get json data from my API :**

```
// Get Specs 
    $.getJSON('https://my_api' , function(specs) {
    console.log(specs);
  
    $.each(specs, function(index, vsp) {
    console.log(vsp);

    var in = vsp.specs[0].value;
    var ch = vsp.specs[1].value;
    var ra = vsp.specs[2].value;
    var ca = vsp.specs[3].value;
    var ba = vsp.specs[4].value;
```

**JSON data Ex:1 :**

```
"specs": [
        {
         "value": "info1"
      },
      {
         "value": "info2"
      },
      {
         "value": "info3"
      },
      {
         "value": "infp4"
      },
      {
         "value": "info5"
      }
   ]
```

**JSON data Ex:2 :**

```
"specs": [
        {
         "value": "info1"
      },
      {
         "value": "info2"
      },
      {
         "value": "info3"
      },
      {
         "value": "infp4"
      }
   ]
```

For the first example, everything works fine, but for the second example i'm having this problem :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
var ba = vsp.specs[4].value; ==> value is undefined
```

How i can skip this var if is undefined ?
Any help would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional chaining (`?.`) operator.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

> The optional chaining operator (`?.`) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

This operator can be helpful in your use case.

---

To use it, simply use the code below.

```js
var ba = vsp.specs[4]?.value;
```

This will, instead of throwing an error if it can't find the `value` property, return `undefined`.

---

This should help with the error. However, you should still add a check for if the variable is `undefined`. You can use something like below.

```js
ba = ba ?? "Fallback";
```

This will use the left-hand side value (`ba`) unless it is `null` or `undefined`, in which case will use the right-hand side value (`"Fallback"`).

An `if` statement can do something similar.

```js
if (typeof ba === "undefined" || ba === null) {
  ba = "Fallback";
}
```

The reason you can't use `!` is because it will evaluate anything of a [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value to be `false`. This will only fallback if it is `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

you can just insert a ? between the property name and the period between the next property.

```
var ba = vsp?.specs?.[4]?.value;
```

also you can use the Nullish coalescing operator :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: The first solution is optional chaining, and reference is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Your link redirects to the French version of MDN.

Comment: I have updated it :)

Answer (score 1):

What about check length of array before access it ?
As I understand It sound like you try to access item at index 4 which was not there since beginning

sample code to check array length from your 2nd sample

```
 var json = {
"specs": [
        {
         "value": "info1"
      },
      {
         "value": "info2"
      },
      {
         "value": "info3"
      },
      {
         "value": "infp4"
      }
   ]};
console.log(Object.keys(json['specs']).length); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

in the json2 it's impossible to get `vsp.specs[4]` because only have positions from 0 to 3 in the array, could ask for the position in the array exists something like

```
var ba = (4<vsp.length) ? vsp.specs[4].value:null;
```

or

```
var ba = vsp?.specs?.[4]?.value;
```